# How do I center a button in WordPress using HTML

Tags: html, css, wordpress, shortcode

How do I center a button in WordPress

This is the code that I put into the page:

```
[one_third last="no"]
    [button color="white" size="large" link="" target=""]
        Button
    [/button]
[/one_third]
[one_third last="no"]
    [button color="white" size="large" link="" target=""]
        Button
    [/button]
[/one_third]
[one_third last="yes"]
    [button color="white" size="large" link="" target=""]
        Button
    [/button]
[/one_third]
```

Comment: Can you put this on JSfiddle or give html code so that somebody can help you

Comment: It appear that you use a theme with short-code for defining buttons, more information needed...

Comment: Yes you are showing us the shortcodes. But this is not the generated html resulting from those shortcodes. You are better off just giving us a link to the page where the problem is.

Comment: What sort of "button" does  your shortcode create? anchor, input or button? Try adding a class to your `[one_third]` columns and then give them a style of `text-align: center;`. If your columns have other content that needs to remain normally justified then you need to contain your buttons in another div that has a class or style of `text-align: center;`.

Answer (score 0):

This is called shortcode,
for change style, you have to find the function for returning for that shortcode,
view the code and apply class to that element or container element,
than you can apply css for that class.

for make center here are examples of css,

```
.element {
     margin: 0 auto;
}

.container_element {
    text-align: center
}
```